# Null Exception on execute http request Android

Tags: android, http, hosting

I have a null Exception executing this code, on "execute" operation and i do not understand why, could you hlep me please ?
Here my code retreive an adresse as : "routeslibre.fr/connexion.php?variable=Departement;;;voie;;;" and provide it to http operation: execute. On this operation an exception is throw which have a null value and i do not understand the reason.... ? Thanks for helping me !

```
    mydataFromHMI = dataFromHMI;
    myFichierPHPbase = FichierPHPbase;

    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject json_data=null;

    try{
        GestionStrings gestionString = new GestionStrings();
        splitData = mydataFromHMI.split(";;;");
        mydataFromHMI = gestionString.blancTraitement(splitData[0]) 
                + ";;;" 
                + gestionString.blancTraitement(splitData[1]) 
                + ";;;";
        String httpRequest = new String("http://routeslibre.fr/"+ myFichierPHPbase + "?variable=" + mydataFromHMI);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(httpRequest);
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

        //If you get the value of response code as 200 then you are getting data from server and 
        //if the response code value >=300 then you have error at your server side.
        //int test = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("taghttppost",""+e.toString());
        isProblemConnexion = true;
    }
```

THe log is:

```
  `  08-02 19:58:57.959: I/dalvikvm-heap(7640): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.421MB for 1647516-byte allocation
08-02 19:58:58.089: I/webclipboard(7640): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@419ff9b8
08-02 19:58:58.164: I/webclipboard(7640): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@419ff9b8
08-02 19:58:58.174: E/SKIA(7640): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed
08-02 19:58:58.324: I/webclipboard(7640): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@419ff9b8
08-02 19:58:58.364: I/Ads(7640): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("1CA948FD73C51AEDDBB30790A88E0DBC");
08-02 19:58:58.514: I/Ads(7640): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":["voiture moto velo bus trameway tram train greve carte geolocalisation"],"preqs":0,"session_id":"10528273920811926641","u_sd":2,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"a15007f67ec6dea","u_w":360,"msid":"free.controls.source","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.0.1","mv":"8013015.com.android.vending","isu":"1CA948FD73C51AEDDBB30790A88E0DBC","cipa":1,"format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"4.android.free.controls.source","hl":"fr","u_h":640,"carrier":"20820","ptime":0,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>
08-02 19:59:02.174: I/taghttppost(7640): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
08-02 19:59:02.174: I/tagconvertstr(7640): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 19:59:02.179: I/connexions(7640): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 19:59:02.179: W/dalvikvm(7640): threadid=19: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c661f8)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at free.controls.source.clien.ConnexionSQL.ConnexionBD(ConnexionSQL.java:213)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at free.controls.source.clien.ConnexionSQL.doInBackground(ConnexionSQL.java:76)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at free.controls.source.clien.ConnexionSQL.doInBackground(ConnexionSQL.java:1)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-02 19:59:02.194: E/AndroidRuntime(7640):     ... 5 more
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640): Activity free.controls.source.forum.ForumActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41bf0540 that was originally added here
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity free.controls.source.forum.ForumActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41bf0540 that was originally added here
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:414)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:282)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:143)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at free.controls.source.clien.ConnexionSQL.onPreExecute(ConnexionSQL.java:84)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at free.controls.source.forum.ForumActivity.onCreate(ForumActivity.java:78)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4533)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
08-02 19:59:02.339: E/WindowManager(7640):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 19:59:03.464: I/GATE(7640): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>`
```

Comment: Post your LogCat so that SO knows whats wrong.

Comment: What are you doing before this code gets called??

Comment: I call it via an  Asynchroneous task : this code is in an AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Check out your java file  ConnexionSQL.java at line 213, the nullpointer exception is generating from this line.

Comment: First of all, Thanks very much to helping me, but the error not comming from this line, this line throw an exception because of the first error before. Moreover the first error is launch (in the debugger) at line 169, during `execute` operation,but i do not know why....

Answer (score 0):

The error coming from this line:

`HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(httpRequest);`

I changed it by this one :

`HttpPost request = new HttpPost(httpRequest);`